# Pausing non-essential CPU processes

Tags: cpu, process

Is it possible to command the CPU to pause all non-essential processes until my program has finished processing? The goal being to reduce the amount of processes competing for CPU processing time, and I am ultimately expecting an improvement in wall-clock running time of my program.

So I want to start my program running, command the CPU to pause non-essential processes except for my program, and when my program terminates then the CPU can resume the previously paused processes.

Comment: I'm running on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

On linux, The obvious initial tactic is to increase the priority of your process using renice.  The lower the [nice value](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/), the higher the priority, with a maximum priority of -20.

(here i create a long running process for example)

```
sleep 100000 &
```

as root grep for the process;

```
ps -ef | grep sleep

500       **4323**  2995  0 18:44 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 100000
500       4371  2995  0 18:45 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

renice the process to a very high priority;

```
renice -20 4323
```

You can also send the SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals to Stop and Continue particular processes like so;

```
skill -STOP -p <processid>
skill -CONT -p <processid>
```

Unfortunately, what constitutes non-essential processes is dependent on your own definition. You can stop all non-root processes by examining the process list, and using the following command to stop all of a particular user's processes temporarily;

```
skill -STOP -u <userid>
skill -CONT -u <userid>
```

Obviously beware of stopping processes such as the shell that spawned your sudo root session.